# SSRS multivalue parameter display

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Let me know how to do this in SSRS:-
If user selects more than one values of a multivalue parameter then display "Multiple" in a textbox
else if the user selects only one value then display that value in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do it. first you can check if the specific Parameter is multivalue or not:

```
 =Parameters! <MultivalueParameterName> .IsMultiValue
```

If above return True the you can check how many selections are made as below:

```
=Parameters! <MultivalueParameterName> .Count
```

Finally if above line return more then 1 then you know that multiple values are selected and set "multiple" as results and if result is 1 then show the exact value as result. The function will look like as below:

```
If parameter.IsMultiValue then
    if parameter.count() > 1
             s = "Multiple" 
Else
     s = parameter.Value
End If
Return s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below expression:
=iif(Parameters!ParameterName.Count>1,"Multiple",Parameters!ParameterName.Value(0))